# Difference of reactivity between anilines and alkyl amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

Imine synthesis is somewhat common and straightforward, to achieve good yields a good practice is to remove the water formed from the condensation reaction by means of a desiccating agent or a Dean-Stark trap.

In the lab I've tried to synthesize the following imines from primary amines and aldehydes.
[image]
The first reaction proceeds with good yields, but in the second the product will not form. I have tried many different reaction condition but none seem to work.
The only explanation that I have come up with as for why this happens has to do with HSAB theory: **2** is resonance stabilized and thus is a soft electrophile, while aniline's free electron pair is delocalized in the aromatic ring making it a soft nucleophile and that's why both can react together to form **3**.

On the second reaction **4** is a hard nucleophile because the electron pair of the amine cannot be delocalized and thus will only react with a hard electrophile.

Is this an acceptable reasoning?
I would be very grateful if anyone could provide references for this subject. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe is a matter of higher basicity of benzylamine.